# Symfony2 and Doctrine2: how to get all tags for a post?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

In my project, I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities: Post and Tag.
(Post has a variable 'tags').

I want to allow the user to search posts through **their name OR their tags** (like on tumblr for exemple)

Let's say I have this in my database:

```
        Name                     Tags
post1: "Recipe with eggs"        cooking, chicken, egg    
post2: "Random Title"            beef, chicken, egg    
post3: "Cooking Fish"            fish, cooking
post4: "Rice and chicken"        rice, meat
```

So if I enter 'chicken egg' in my search form, I have to return only post1 (because of the tags), post2 (because of the tags) AND post4 (because of the name).

But I also want to retrieve, **for each post**, all their associated tags (cooking, chicken and egg for post1, ...).

In my Controller, I have this:

```
//$data['search'] comes from a form and contains for exemple 'chicken egg'
$searchString = $data['search'];
$searchString = explode(' ',$searchString);
$list = $repository->getPostByTag($searchString);
```

In my PostRepository.php I have created this:

```
    public function getPostByTag($searchString)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')->leftJoin('p.tags','t');
        $i = 0;
        foreach($searchString as $tag)
        {
           $query->orWhere('t.name like :tag'.$i.' OR p.name like :percent_tag'.$i)
              ->setParameter('tag'.$i, $tag)
              ->setParameter(':percent_tag'.$i,'%'.$tag.'%');
           $i++;
        }
        $query->leftJoin('p.author','a')
              ->leftJoin('p.tags','t2')
              ->addSelect('t2')
              ->addSelect('a'); 
    }
```

But this "getPostByTag" method gives me very random results...
How can I get **every posts and their associated tags** by **searching through their name and theirs tags**?

Comment: Can you post the resulting DQL from the profiler? I'm building you a solution as well but this will help a lot.

Comment: Also wanted to say welcome to SO. You've written a great first question and it's refreshing to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this one a whirl for me? Note the modified method name due to the fact that we're fetching multiple Posts with multiple Tags.

```
public function getPostsByTags($tagArray = array()) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $i = 1;
    $tagObjects = this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')
        ->findByName(array('name' => $tagArray)); // This is case-insensitive by default

    foreach ($tagObjects as $tagObj) {
        $query->orWhere('?'.$i.' MEMBER OF p.tags')->setParameter($i, $tagObj);
        $i++;
    }

    foreach ($tagArray as $tag) {
        $query->orWhere('p.name LIKE ?'.$i)->setParameter($i, '%'.$tag.'%');
        $i++;
    }

    $query->leftJoin('p.tags', 't')
        ->leftJoin('p.author', 'a')
        ->addSelect('t')->addSelect('a')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! It worked like a charm. Didn't know about this 'MEMBER OF' operator

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an error in how you are doing your parameter settings.  You don't surround `tag` with `%` - was that intentional because you want tags to match exactly? Also you shouldn't have the `:` for the `percent_tag`.

```
$query->orWhere('t.name like :tag'.$i.' OR p.name like :percent_tag'.$i)
   ->setParameter('tag'.$i, $tag)
   ->setParameter('percent_tag'.$i,'%'.$tag.'%');
```

Comment: Since the resulting build will have more than one `tag` and `percent_tag` if there's multiple search string arguments, it makes sense and will work out correctly, however I would use numbered parameters instead.

Comment: Would you just use numbered parameters because it looks cleaner given this sort of implementation?

Comment: That's right, they end up doing the same thing though. I also think OP intentionally wants to leave wildcards out of the tag search (but not the title search.)

Comment: You're probably right.  In that case you wouldn't be able to do numbered parameters since one is using wildcards and one isn't.

Comment: Au contraire: `'t.name like ?'.$i.' OR p.name like ?'.($i+1)`

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with duplicate $i when you jump to the next iteration of the loop though?

Comment: Oh yeah my brain had already forgot and was thinking about using it in a `for(` heh

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < (count($searchString) * 2); $i = $i + 2)` :)